# how to convert object datatype of date to date in python?

Tags: python, pandas, date

I Have a variable where I  have stored date but whenever I  am opening that data-frame in my ExcelSheet  it is taking that variable in general format instead of date I had date in this format

'# Date: Jan 14, 2023'

which I converted into '1/14/2023'  this format using the below Code
Var =  datetime.strptime(Var, '%b %d, %Y').strftime('%#m/%d/%Y')

I am getting desired output which is '1/14/2023' the only problem I am facing is that while generating  the excel of data-frame  I am getting datatype of date in general format instead of date which will cause problem while uploading the excel sheet in tableau and the datatype for date in my jupyter notebook is object whenever I tried converting the data-type into int or float it drastically changed the values

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TFwl.png)

my desired format output

Comment: Please, show your code [mre], instead of explaining what you are doing

Comment: @buran i have already shown my one line of code

Comment: The Excel sometimes format the date for you, make sure to disable formatting in Excel. That could be a possible issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert content of Object datatype to Date datatype in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37510348/convert-content-of-object-datatype-to-date-datatype-in-python)